# Add a constraint to check whether a value isn't in 2 arrays in 2 columns at the same time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm implementing some kind of upvoting and downvoting system in my web app.
In order to do so, the logic behind requires that the user who upvoted cannot downvote at the same time.
My SQL logic is the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE "CONCEPT_SLIDE"."CONCEPT" (
    "concept_id" serial NOT NULL,
    "owner_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "title" text NOT NULL,
    "description" text NOT NULL,
    "tags" text [] NULL,
    "picture_links" text [] NULL,
    "website_link" TEXT NULL,
    "state" "CONCEPT_SLIDE"."CONCEPT_STATE" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ONLY A CONCEPT',
    "users_who_upvoted" int [] NULL CONSTRAINT chk_upvote CHECK (ELEMENT) ,
    "users_who_downvoted" int [] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_table_16 PRIMARY KEY ("concept_id"),
    CONSTRAINT FK_43 FOREIGN KEY ("owner_id") REFERENCES "CONCEPT_SLIDE"."USER" ("user_id"),
   );
```

I want to make sure that the user ID in `users_who_upvoted` (or resp. `users_who_downvoted`) can't be in `users_who_downvoted` (or resp. `users_who_upvoted`)
How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array overlap operation in a check constraint.

```
...
CHECK (NOT users_who_upvoted && users_who_downvoted)
...
```

But I would recommend not to use arrays here at all (also concerning all the others you have in that table) but go the traditional relational way with (linking) tables and foreign keys, etc.. Otherwise you got a recipe for headaches there.

Comment: Are arrays usually a no-no in SQL databases? I'm quite new to designing them from scratch for apps so I'd like to know whether it's a bad practice to use them here

Comment: @Fares: An array (or "composite" columns, also XML, JSON, ...) may be fine, if you never want to work with or filter on the single elements in queries. But for for votes you may want to show a user all their votes, i.e. filter for their ID. With a column in a table that's a simple `SELECT * FROM vote_table WHERE user_id_column = <user id value>`, with an array this gets awkward pretty quick. Same goes with listing posts that have a certain tag, etc.. And you cannot put foreign key constraints (easily) on the IDs in an array to ensure referential integrity.

Comment: @Fares: Finally, with arrays, optimization (indexing) is also at least trickier.

Comment: @Fares: Oh and another thing: You may want to avoid identifiers in double quotes like `"CONCEPT_SLIDE"."CONCEPT"`. That makes the identifier case sensitive and you have to call it exactly with the correct case and the double quotes **all** the time from then on. That just tends to make things unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an awkward data model.  Why not simply have a table with "votes" and a flag on whether it is an upvote or downvote?  Your question is not 100% clear about what is being voted on, so I'll just generically call it "entity":

```
create table entity_votes (
    entity_vote_id int generated always as identity,
    entity_id int references <whatever is being voted on>,
    user_id int references users(id),
    up_or_down int check (up_or_down in (-1, 1)),
    unique (entity_id, user_id),
    created_at timestamp
    . . . 
);
```

The unique constraint guarantees that a user votes on an entity only once.  Columns such as `created_at` capture the timing for each vote.